# troubles with getting c# plugin 3.0 and resharper to work properly

Tags: sonarqube

we have upgraded to SonarQube 4.3 and C# plugin 3.0 but we are struggling to get the integration with resharper working.

- Which version of the Reshaprer plugin shall be available for SonarQube 4.3? 
  In update center I find version 1.0 but when I look at the reshaper plugin documentation there shall be a version 1.1 available.
- Can I upgrade to the resharper plugin to version 1.1 in any other way? I have tried to put the 1.1 jar file in the plugin directory but then SonarQube refuse to start due to missing dependencies.

The reason for wanting version 1.1 is that we need to use our own dotsettings file and this seems to not be available in version 1.0. We also can´t get the reuseReport mode to work at all with the current installed version. Even if we use “sonar.resharper.mode=skip” resharper is trigged in the analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation is quite messy, there indeed was a ".NET ReSharper" plugin available in version 1.0 and 1.1. This plugin is only compatible with the .NET ecosystem 2.1.
C# 3.0 is only compatible with a "ReSharper" plugin, which only exists in version 1.0.

Please refer to the following documentation: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/ReSharper+Plugin

Indeed the ReSharper 1.0 plugin does not support reuseReport mode (and it is not planned to add it currently).

However, there are plans to be able to import/export DotSettings files from/to SonarQube quality profiles: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3738

Have also a look at the example project: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/csharp

Final note: The .NET ecosystem 2.1 is not compatible with SonarQube 4.3.

Comment: The reuseReport mode seems to be quite a nice thing since it seems to be the preferred way to do an analysis at least according to the .NET Resharper documentation. According to the documentation the analysis times would be reduced if called externally